# Electron JS: Prevent navigation to a specific pathname

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

When using **loadURL** to load my website I want to prevent users from navigating to two pages. I need to do this within the Electron app.

For example, In my application I am in:

```
https://WebsiteApp.com
```

But I want to prevent navigation to the page:

```
https://WebsiteApp.com/security
```

Is there any way to prevent navigation for this path?

```
pathname: '/security'
```

Comment: How are you using `loadURL`?

Comment: What's wrong with those two pages? Surely the user could always visit them in their browser anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 'Route Guards', it's also known as **Navigation Guards** implemented in some frameworks like Angular or Vue, react in that case use React router and hooks to do that including typescript.

> Anyway check [this explanation](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/using-route-guards-actions-and-web-components) where you can redirect page depending of the auth level among others, it's the long explanation but may help you.

[image]

> This **AuthGuard** implementation expects to create an internal instance from `AuthorizationService` to validate the access through the `pageEnabled` function.

```ts
// auth-guard.ts

import { Commands, Context, RedirectResult } from '@vaadin/router';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization-service';
import { PageEnabled } from './page-enabled';

export class AuthGuard implements PageEnabled {

  private authService: AuthorizationService;

  constructor() {
    this.authService = new AuthorizationService();
  }

  public async pageEnabled(context: Context, commands: Commands, pathRedirect?: string): Promise<RedirectResult | undefined> {
    const isAuthenticated = await this.authService.isAuthorized();

    if(!isAuthenticated) {
      console.warn('User not authorized', context.pathname);
     return commands.redirect(pathRedirect? pathRedirect: '/');
    }

    return undefined;
  }
}
```

> > Also, this class needs to implement the PageEnabled interface defined **into /shared/auth/page-enabled.ts**

```ts
//page-enabled.ts

import { Commands, Context, RedirectResult } from '@vaadin/router';

export interface PageEnabled {
  pageEnabled(
    context: Context,
    commands: Commands,
    pathRedirect?: string
  ): Promise<RedirectResult | undefined>;
}
```